# @OneToOne relations hibernate question

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I'm working in a project using Hibernate +JPA. I have this Entity class:

```
    @Entity
public class CafeUser implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Integer userId;
    @Column    
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String userPassword;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String userEmail;
    @Column
    private String userAddress;
    @Column
    private String userCountry;
    @Column
    private String userState;
    @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime userDateOfBirth;
    @Column
    private String userSex;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="userAccountingDetailsId", referencedColumnName="userAccountingDetailsId")
    private AccountingDetails accountingDetails;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private InvestorProfile investorProfile;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private Set<UserProfileAnswer> userProfileAnswers;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    private Set<MoneyHealth> userMoneyHealths;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
    private Set<LifePlanning> lifePlannings;

    getters-setters
}
```

If you can see, the field userEmail is declared as unique, and if there is a duplicate of CafeUser entity in the DB, it doesn't insert the entity.
BUT, the fields "investorProfile" and "accountingDetails" get inserted even if associated with a user that have an email already registered in the database.

What I'm doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

set hibernate property `hibernate.show_sql` to true and see what SQL statements are getting generated. Also check if you are doing the persistence in transaction.

Comment: I'm persisting through the EntityManager, and yes, I'm persisting in the transaction. Do I have to rollback the transaction when an PersistenceException is caught during persist() ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I misinterpreted the @OneToOne relation. Now the investorProfile and AccountingDetails holds one key for one user and it's all set.